# What is the use of Point object in macro reference?

Tags: emeditor

In emeditor macro reference, there is an Point object. The description contains only this:

```
Properties
x Represents the horizontal (or character) position of the Point object. 
y Represents the vertical (or line) position of the Point object. 

Version
Supported on EmEditor Professional Version 17.0 or later.
```

There is no use example, and no telling on how to create such an object.
So what is this object used for and how to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[Point](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_point_index.html)** object is currently used in the **[SerialToLogical](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_document_serialtological.html)**, **[LogicalToView](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_document_logicaltoview.html)**, and **[ViewToLogical](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_document_viewtological.html)** methods of the **Document** object.